# how to use value from the for-loop outside it java

Tags: java, for-loop, calculation

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class App {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       double input;
       double netto=0;
       Scanner value = new Scanner(System.in);

       for(int x=0;x<4;x++){
           System.out.println("Please enter the number");
            input = value.nextInt();
           if(input>=300){
               netto= input - input*0.30;
           }
           else {
               netto =input- input*0.20;
           }
           
       }
       netto=+netto;

       System.out.println(netto);

       
   }
}
```

i want that the code adds the results after subtracting part of them according to the entered value.
the problem is that the code saves the last result only and shows it.

Comment: This line does nothing: `netto=+netto;` It just assigns the value of the variable `netto` to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you meant to accumulate the values into `netto` using `+=` instead of overriding it with `=`:

```java
for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
   System.out.println("Please enter the number");
   input = value.nextInt();
   if (input>=300) {
       netto += input - input * 0.30; // Here
   }
   else {
       netto += input - input * 0.20; // And here
   }
}
```